# How to get extra everyday clothing?

Tags: the-sims

Is there any way for my sims to buy extra clothing for everyday? I SWEAR there was a way to do it, but I can't remember how. It seems like all I can get is swimwear, formal, high fashion, and jammies.

Comment: To be clear, we're definitely talking about the original Sims, correct?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to switch your cloths with using the "Change Clothes" interaction with a dressers or wardrobe or similar furniture.